# Search in File explorer displaying incorrect metadata

Tags: uwp, windows-10, explorer

Take a PEF raw image from a Pentax 645Z. Sample here 
https://github.com/Ponant/StorageFileQueryResultBug/tree/master/ImageSample .

The Raw Image Extension is installed from the Store.

The result is that now I can see the thumbnail of my PEF file in `File Explorer`, and if I right click the PEF file to get the `properties-->details` I get the correct metadata such as Dimensions and Date Taken.

However, if I do a search in the search bar of FE and type in the name of the file "Sample", the search result shows the image, but the date taken field as well as other metadata are not shown.
To confirm this bug, if I type DateTaken:[] ,
I see the PEF file appearing as a search result,
hence confirming that the AQS does not see a Date Taken info for this file. Furthermore, if I right click this image and head to the details, the metadata are indeed gone.

**Question: Which AQS command should I execute to get the correct result?**

As a side note, this issue also occurs in UWP apps using AQS. It also occurs in the Photos App from Microsoft. In the sense that, you will get 2 different results, one of which is wrong, if you

1) Double click image in File Explorer, which launches Photos App and right click image from there, the information appears correct

2) In contrast to 1, in File explorer, do the search first, e.g. put in the name of the file, double click on the image, which launches the Photos app, and head for the information in this App. This time the details information through the eyes of the Photos app are empty, similar to FE's bug.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I tested with JPG file and it works with above scenario, I suppose this is file type is not compatible with FE, please feel free post this with Windows Feed Back Hub app.

Comment: The Raw Image Extension supports PEF files, and indeed I have no problem with other PEF files. But there are cameras where this does not work, such as the 645Z (tested picture), whilst it is supported by libraw.org (on which the extension is built). There are other cameras showing similar results in FE.